# source map's in mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement, mini-css-extract-plugin

I can't seem to get source maps to work with the `mini-css-extract-plugin`. I had them working with `style-loader`.

```
devtool: argv.mode === 'development' ? 'eval' : 'none',

[...]

test: /\.scss$|\.css$/i,
use: [
     {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {sourceMap: argv.mode === 'development', hmr: argv.hot},
     },
     {
         loader: 'css-loader',
         options: {sourceMap: argv.mode === 'development', importLoaders: 1},
     },

[...]

plugins: [
    [...]
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: argv.mode === 'development' ? '[name].css' : '[contenthash].css',
        chunkFilename: argv.mode === 'development' ? '[id].css' : '[contenthash].css',
    }),
]
```

A bit of brackground information:
I've always used the `style-loader` to get hot module replacement to work in dev mode and `mini-css-extract-plugin` for production.

Now the `mini-css-extract-plugin` supports hmr which is awesome since i won't have to deal with FOUC in development anymore.

But having no source map to at least tell me from which file a style is coming from is annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While writing the question i found a possible solution which did end up working.

I defined `devtool` as `eval` which is the cheapest option. I don't entirely get how it works but it isn't a real source map, rather it wraps the entire source in an eval statements and tells the browser that is a specific file which was fine with me but this strategy obviously can't work with css files.

What I did is define devtool as `cheap-source-map` which seems to be the fastest option that does not rely on eval statements.

I also think i completely misunderstood the sourceMap option of loaders. I only need them when generating a full source map which shows the original source code. (although i haven't tested that completely)